# Menú HTML no funciona en host

Tags: html, css, html5, responsive, hosting

Tengo una página Web a la que le agregue un menú con sus diferentes opciones, y a una de esas opciones subsecciones, como podrán ver el código. Hago prueba de mi página local y me funciona perfectamente en pantalla completa y de manera responsive; mi problema es que, al momento de subirlo a un host (en mi caso a HostGator), no funciona el menú de manera responsive, es decir, cuando yo doy clic a la opción de `Certificación de sistemas de gestión` no se muestran las opciones de `ISO 9001:2015`, `ISO 14001:2015` e `ISO 45001:2018`; pero cuando esta en pantalla completa si funciona, y de manera local no me da ningún error y si me dirige a los HTML a los que los direcciono, ya que mis nombres si coinciden a como se llama el archivo `.html`

Espero me puedan ayudar por favor

Código HTML:

```
<nav class="menu navegacion">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Certificación de sistemas de gestión<span class="icon-down-open"></span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="ISO-9001-2015.html">ISO 9001:2015</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ISO-14001-2015.html">ISO 14001:2015</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ISO-45001-2018.html">ISO 45001:2018</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="acerca_de.html">Acerca de</a></li>
                    <li><a href="proceso_certificacion.html">Proceso de Certificación</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Código CSS:

```
/* ------------------------------------------menu--------------------------------------------*/

header {
    height: 7rem;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

#btn-menu {
    display: none;
}

header label {
    font-size: 3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.menu ul {
    background: #000000;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

menu a:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

menu a span {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    header {
        height: 7rem;
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #FFF;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
    }
    header label {
        display: block;
    }
    .menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5rem;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    .menu ul {
        display: block;
        background: #555;
    }
    .menu ul li:hover ul {
        display: none;
        position: static;
    }
    .menu a span {
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
    }
    #btn-menu:checked~.menu {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    /* .menu ul ul {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }*/
    .menu ul ul a {
        padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

el error esta en los estilos, actualízalo a lo siguiente:

```
    header {
    height: 7rem;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

#btn-menu {
    display: none;
}

header label {
    font-size: 3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.menu ul {
    background: #000000;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

menu a:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

menu a span {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.submenu ul li:hover { /*cambia el color de las opciones ISO al colocar el puntero sobre alguna opción, aplica para cualquier tamaño de pantalla*/
    background: #555;
}
@media (max-width:768px) { /*todo lo que esta dentro de esta sección aplica para pantallas con un ancho menor o igual a 768 pixeles*/
    header {
        height: 7rem;
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #FFF;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
    }
    header label {
        display: block;
    }
    .menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5rem;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-90%); /*deja visible el 10% del menú*/
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    .menu:hover {
        transform: translateX(0%); /*deja visible el 100% del menú cuando se coloca el puntero sobre el menú*/
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }
.submenu:hover ul {/*hace visible las opciones ISO al colocar el puntero encima del sub menú Certificación de sistemas de gestión*/
    display: block;
}
    .menu ul {
        display: block;
    }
    .menu ul li:hover ul {
        position: static;
    }
    .menu a span {
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
    }
    #btn-menu:checked~.menu {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    /* .menu ul ul {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }*/
    .menu ul ul a {
        padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: @BetaM cierto, he editado mi respuesta

Comment: Hola @Ben he utilizado tu código y si me muestra las ISO, solo tengo una duda, hay alguna función u opción para que al dar clic en `Certificación de sistemas de gestión` se suban u oculten de nuevo las opciones?

Comment: @MayraXimenaVargas claro, lo puedes hacer con javascript o bien jquery, en este enlace explican como funciona y como puedes aplicar el efecto toggle con jquery: (https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)